# Logstash output to custom index if file path is "/file/path"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

this is my working logstash config

```
    output {
  if[@metadata][pipeline] {
   elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false 
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" 
    pipeline => "%{[@metadata][pipeline]}" 
    user => some_user
    password => pass_4_some_user
   }
  } else {
  elasticsearch { 
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
   manage_template => false 
   index =>"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" 
   user => some_user
   password => pass_4_some_user
   }
  }  
 }
```

I need if file path is equal `/file/path` index must be `test_file_index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`

My new config file

```
output {
    if "/file/path" in [@file][path] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
            index =>"test_file_index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => some_user
            password => pass_4_some_user
           }
    } else {
        if[@metadata][pipeline] {
            elasticsearch {
             hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
             manage_template => false
             index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
             pipeline => "%{[@metadata][pipeline]}"
             user => some_user
             password => pass_4_some_user
            }
           } else {
           elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            manage_template => false
            index =>"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => some_user
            password => pass_4_some_user
            }
           }
    }
}
```

Not working properly. If someone knows what is the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output {
    if [log][file][path] == "/full/file/path" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            ...
```

This one work for me.
If someone care )))

Comment: Ok you didn't tell what was the input, but if it's coming from beats, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the condition should just be

```
if "/file/path" in [path] {
```

As the file input stores the file path in the `path` field, not `@file.path`

Comment: According to https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-out-put-based-on-log-file-path/196766 the correct way is [log][file][path]