# Logstash how to give different index name to ElasticSearch based on file name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have the following .conf file for Logstash:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/elastic/logstash-8.3.2/config/*.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NULL"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ";"
        columns => ["name","deposit","month"]
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
            "deposit" => "integer"
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "payment_test"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

I get inputs from 10 .csv files, which have names like `in-0.csv`, `in-1.csv` and so on. I want the index names in ElasticSearch to be `payment_test-0`, `payment_test-1` and so on for the corresponding .csv input files (the data in `in-0.csv` would be in index `payment_test-0` and so on). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logstash output to custom index if file path is "/file/path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112244/logstash-output-to-custom-index-if-file-path-is-file-path)

Comment: @SagarPatel Unfortunately not, I don't use beats and I want the index names to increment like `payment-test-0`, `payment-test-1`, `payment-test-2` etc. according to their input file names. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This will apply same even for logstash as well. You can add If condition in Output of logstash as well. You can add if condition and check what is file name and based on that you can set index name.

Comment: @SagarPatel If I add if conditions for each file, wouldn't I need 10 if statements for 10 files? Can't I just get the last part of the filename like `filename.substr(3)` in JavaScript and use the result in the index name as variable like %{customName}?

Comment: yes, you can do that. In you filter plugin add mutate plugin which will create new field and that field you can combine with your index name inside output plugin.

Comment: @SagarPatel I am very new to the ELK stack and Logstash, can you give an example please?

Comment: Please chekc my answer. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do it like this with [the `dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) instead of `grok`:

```
filter {
    ... your other filters

    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "[log][file][path]" => "%{?ignore_path}/in-%{file_no}.csv"
      }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "payment_test-%{file_no}"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: When I run with these settings, I get the following error and no new indices: `Dissector mapping, field not found in event {"field"=>"path", "event"=>{"log"=>{"file"=>{"path"=>"C:/elastic/logstash-8.3.2/config/in-4.csv"}}, "name"=>"Name", "event"=>{"original"=>"Name;35215;January\r"}, "message"=>"Name;35215;January\r", "deposit"=>35215, "month"=>"January", "@timestamp"=>2022-07-29T12:49:55.888897300Z, "@version"=>"1", "host"=>{"name"=>"PC"}}}`

Comment: Good point, it's not `path` but in ECS it's called `[log][file][path]`, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You can create new field as shown below and that you can use in index name:

```json
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/elastic/logstash-8.3.2/config/*.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NULL"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ";"
        columns => ["name","deposit","month"]
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
            "deposit" => "integer"
        }
    }
grok {
    match => ["path","%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:file_name}\.csv"]
  }
grok { match => { "file_name " => "^.{3}(?<file_no>.)" } }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "payment-test-%{file_no}"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

I have used `file_name` field name for file name but you can used your original field in which file name is coming.

Comment: Seems to work but I can't see any new indices in Postman also the outputs in the console has `"tags" => [ [0] "_grokparsefailure"],`. Do I need to create the indices first and then run Logstash?

Comment: If you have the index as a template , they should automatically be created ?

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G I use the exact .conf posted, so I don't think I have the index as a template. How do I create the index as a template?

Comment: is your field name is correct ?

Comment: @SagarPatel In the grok config, `file_name` should be `path` instead, hence the `_grokparsefailure`

Comment: @Val Yes, thats right and I have added same comment in my answer as well in last line. because i have taken `file_name` as just example.

Comment: Yes, though the file name is always stored in the `path` variable by the `file` input plugin, so it's known

Comment: @YağızCanAslan Please check my updated answer where i have added grok for getting file_name from path and which is used in next grok for number. I think so this should be work for you.